# Need to extract info out of HWInfo

Tags: linux

I need to extract information like Serial and Product out of HWInfo. Right now I tried `hwinfo --bios | grep 'Serial:'` and I get more the I need. First I would like the information after the actual Serial: and I have no clue how to pipe that only. Second problem is by grepping the 'Serial' I get 3 different Serial, if I look at the complete print out of HWInfo the Serial I actually need is in the sub-section of System Info: #1 so is there a way to grep the Serial under that only?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question and created this one as first step:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'hwinfo_example.txt';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
while (my $row = <$fh>) {
    chomp $row;
    if( index($row, '  Chassis Info') eq 0 ){
        #print "$row\n";
        while (my $row = <$fh>){
            chomp $row;
            if( (length($row) < 5) or (substr($row, 2, 1) ne ' ') ){
                last ;
            }
            if( index($row, '    Serial:') eq 0 ){
                print "$row\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my example i found the serial under Chassis Info, so this one searches for Chassis Info and in the next lines for the serial